# multithreaded crawler while using tor proxy

Tags: python, multithreading, tor, socks

I am trying to build multi threaded crawler that uses tor proxies:
I am using following to establish tor connection:

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
controller = Controller.from_port(port=9151)
def connectTor():
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9150)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket


def renew_tor():
    global request_headers
    request_headers = {
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "User-Agent": random.choice(BROWSERS),
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Referer": "http://thewebsite2.com",
        "Connection": "close"
    }

    controller.authenticate()
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

Here is url fetcher:

```
def get_soup(url):
    while True:
        try:
            connectTor()
            r = requests.Session()
            response = r.get(url, headers=request_headers)
            the_page = response.content.decode('utf-8',errors='ignore')
            the_soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page, 'html.parser')
            if "captcha" in the_page.lower():
                print("flag condition matched while url: ", url)
                #print(the_page)
                renew_tor()
            else:
                return the_soup
                break
        except Exception as e:
            print ("Error while URL :", url, str(e))
```

I am then creating multithreaded fetch job:

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(200) as executor:
            for url in zurls:
                future = executor.submit(fetchjob,url)
```

then I am getting following error, which I am not seeing when I use multiprocessing:

```
 Socket connection failed (Socket error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure)
```

I would appreciate Any advise to avoid socks error and improving the performance of crawling method to make it multi threaded.

Comment: Does this resolve it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035413/general-socks-server-failure-when-switching-identity-using-stem

Comment: while my code is inspired by the code in the link, I am trying to build multi threaded code, so I am having an issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect example of why monkey patching `socket.socket` is bad.

This replaces the socket used by *all* `socket` connections (which is most everything) with the SOCKS socket.

When you go to connect to the controller later, it attempts to use the SOCKS protocol to communicate instead of establishing a direct connection.

Since you're already using `requests`, I'd suggest getting rid of SocksiPy and the `socks.socket = socks.socksocket` code and using the SOCKS [proxy](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) functionality built into requests:

```
proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
}

response = r.get(url, headers=request_headers, proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this resolved the socket issue, however then I am getting (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",),))

Comment: Is that error in relation to requests fetching the URL?  Does it happen if you just try issuing one request through the SOCKS proxy to the target site?

Comment: This error doesn't happen all the time. Many threads are succeeding. Even if I run in single thread mode I sometimes get this error. However, since the I have made get_soup() method resilient , I am still able to crawl.