# Tor + Mongodb +localhost27017

Tags: mongodb, scrapy, tor

When I run my crawler, I get the error message:

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: Socket error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure

I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful if you could [edit] the question to include the code of your crawler as that might help folks spot what is causing the error. If you indent the code with four spaces it will display formatted as code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245748/multithreaded-crawler-while-using-tor-proxy/48245845#48245845